# Half a wife, did you say?

Tags: riddle, literature

> My first and my second are in HUSBANDRY,
>   Though one is in UNION, one ZOOLOGY.
>   My third is in DUBITABLY, in SUFFERABLE;
>   My fourth and fifth are in BUSINESS and in SEPARABLE.
>   My sixth is in GOAL, while my seventh’s in THRALL;
>   My whole is a person – a mother to all.

**Who am I?**

*A correct answer should explain each line...*

**Hint:**

> Though this riddle is designed to *look* like your typical 'My first is in...' riddle, the solution is not found through the usual method for solving these. The answer is **not** seven letters long...

Comment: rot13(YBY, V gevrq gb oehgr sbepr gur bcgvbaf sbyybjvat lbhe ehyrf. Urer vf n yvfg bs 7,000 bcgvbaf: uggcf://cnfgrova.pbz/iRnf6Ksg )

Comment: @thewallrus Good luck with that! The way this puzzle works I'm pretty sure the right answer is not even on that list... That's a hint in itself but I'll post a formal hint this weekend if nobody gets it sooner...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer is...

> **Molly Weasley** from Harry Potter!
>  The words describe each of her seven children quite precisely, I suppose:
>  The first, **Bill**, is husband (*union*) to Fleur Delacour.
>  The second, **Charlie**, is also in husbandry, but of the animal kind, because he breeds dragons.
>  The third is **Percy** who indubitably insufferable as a Gryffindor prefect.
>  The four and the fifth are **Fred** and **George**, inseparable as a result of being twins and in business selling joke objects.
>  Sixth is **Ron**, who is a keeper in the Quidditch team, similar to a goalie in soccer.
>  Seventh is **Ginny**, who was in Voldemort's thrall during *Chamber of Secrets*.

Comment: Bingo! Well done NudgeNudge :) Can you explain the title too, out of interest?

Comment: I've awarded you the checkmark since your answer is correct, but if you can edit in an explanation of the title when you've worked it out that would round this off nicely... Thanks!

Comment: @Stiv Thanks! I haven't figured that one out yet, so if anybody can help with that it'll be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, you are clearly referring to the

> YULE SOT

She is the life and death of every Christmas party, and most certainly a mother to us all.

Comment: Again... no... **Look at the tags.**

Comment: Sorry for making a little joke. Next time I'll be sure to have no fun at all.

Comment: Baha - it did make me laugh (out loud, too), I'll grant you that! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is too general, since I don't know if I should take first letter or any letter from words, or if it is more "enigmatic" - still one can fit almost anything:

> 1. Silk (HUSBANDRY + UNION), also could be wool or fibre
>  2. Animal (HUSBANDRY + ZOOLOGY) or some specific animal
>  3. Pain enduring (SUFFERABLE + DUBITABLY)
>  4. Interest (money and stuff - BUSINESS) or finance, money, class
>  5. [Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension) (SEPARABLE) or divided
>  6. Net (place to score GOAL in football) or aim, purpose, mark, score, dream…
>  7. [Slave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrall) (THRALL)
>  All first letters together - [Sapiens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_sapiens)

Comment: Interesting... It's not the answer, but genuinely interesting to see your interpretation here. This was intended as a play on the traditional "My first is in..." riddles - but not in this way! **The tags are important.** :)

Comment: @Stiv I don't know what traditional "My first is in..." riddles are? But I found some puzzles here on site, will look into that.